# Reg:Display image on crystal report

Tags: image, crystal-reports

We are using Crystal report XI, have to show image on the report, right now we are able to show the images. here my problem is we are cropping the image with a fixed width and height then converting the image into binary array (one way to display images on report) in this way images are blurred.  Reason to do like this is we may have big size images also for that we are cropping images. Is there any way to display images with fixed size in the report.

Note: We may have small and big images also finally we need to display with a constant size on report.

Regards,
Chakradhar.

Comment: Where are the pictures coming from? Are they stored in a database, or are you inserting them directly into the report?

Comment: we are storing images on database only.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't yo store the pictures as binary in the database and save yourself the conversion when inserting them into the report? You would need a BLOB column in your database in order to be able to insert the pictures into your database. Alternatively you could insert the images as OLE objects instead of pictures and also decreasing the color depth and using the bitmap format (.bmp) will help you keep the file size down.